# Does Graphql query the database itself?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, odata

In .NET C#, we used Odata to filter, page, sort the database results from SQL database. Odata in .NET would actually go into the database, and query WHERE, ORDER By Filters to database, instead of extracting all the database results, and applying filtering on the api memory.

I am curious if GraphQL, queries the database internally or applies filtering on the API memory set.

**Resource:**

https://graphql.org/

Comment: My relatively limited experience with GraphQL says that GraphQL doesn't have anything to do with data access. It's essentially an alternative to a REST API, and doesn't have anything to do with how data is persisted, retrieved, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphQL is mainly a specification that defines a query language , a type system , a way/framework such that you have to follow it to implement for querying or mutating the data based on this query language and the type system. (i.e. implement various resolvers in the GraphQL term).

It does not define anythings related to where the data should be stored.  So it does not define anything related to the SQL and SQL database.

> I am curious if GraphQL, queries the database internally or applies
> filtering on the API memory set.

So it depends on how you implement it. To have a good performance, of course you have to convert the query type that you defined to an efficient SQL with an efficient where and limit clause , and send to DB to query the result set internally.